# Connect Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 to SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I want to use my database in Visual Studio. I attach the database in SQL Server and when I want to run the project in Visual Studio 2010, I get this error:

http://i57.tinypic.com/2cz3rra.jpg

I enabled TCP/IP and disabled the firewall, and in SQL Server, remote connection is checked. My port is 1433 and everything is ok for Enable remote connection.

I connect to SQL Server by localhost .. and don't know what is my instance

Perhaps my project is not work good and error is for my project ..

I put my project link in first comment , any body can check it for errors ? This is very important for me !!

Comment: Have you verified you have access to the server and database(step 6 of the linked troubleshooting steps)? Can you connect with SSMS?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your id has access on the specified database(and server) or not. Also check whether you've enabled SQL server browser or not. Required services for the server in  SQL configuration manager should be running.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string or maybe your firewall is blocking the connection